# How can I make it so that I can do a delete even when there's a foreign key and row in another table?

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectiveDetail] (
    [ObjectiveDetailId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectiveId]       INT            NOT NULL,
    [Number]            INT            NOT NULL,
    [Text]              NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ObjectiveDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ObjectiveDetailId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectiveDetailObjective] FOREIGN KEY ([ObjectiveId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Objective] ([ObjectiveId])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectiveTopic] (
    [ObjectiveDetailId] INT NOT NULL,
    [SubTopicId]        INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ObjectiveTopicObjectiveDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ObjectiveDetailId] ASC, [SubTopicId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectiveTopicObjectiveDetail] FOREIGN KEY ([ObjectiveDetailId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ObjectiveDetail] ([ObjectiveDetailId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectiveTopicSubTopic] FOREIGN KEY ([SubTopicId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SubTopic] ([SubTopicId])
);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NobjectiveDetail_Number_IX]
    ON [dbo].[ObjectiveDetail]([ObjectiveId] ASC, [Number] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Objective_ObjectiveDetailId_IX]
    ON [dbo].[ObjectiveDetail]([ObjectiveDetailId] ASC);
```

What I was trying to do was to delete an ObjectiveDetail. But if there is a row in the ObjectiveTopic table then the delete fails.

Is there some way that I can also delete of the other row in the ObjectiveTopic table when the ObjectiveDetail row gets deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the constraint so that it has ON DELETE CASCADE enabled.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.LocalData
   DROP CONSTRAINT FK_ReferenceDataLocaldata 

ALTER TABLE dbo.LocalData
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ReferenceDataLocaldata_Cascade
  FOREIGN KEY (ForeignID) REFERENCES dbo.ReferenceData(ForeignPK) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Essentially all you do is add ON DELETE CASCADE to the end of the add constraint command

To apply this to your question, we need to change

```
ALTER TABLE ObjectiveTopic
DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectiveTopicObjectiveDetail]
```

to

```
ALTER TABLE ObjectiveTopic
CREATE CONSTRAINT [FK_ObjectiveTopicObjectiveDetail] FOREIGN KEY ([ObjectiveDetailId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ObjectiveDetail] ([ObjectiveDetailId]) ON DELETE CASCASE
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Which of the tables should I change?

Comment: You change the constraint that you want the delete to move across, in this case it will be FK_ObjectiveTopicObjectiveDetail

Comment: Hmm reading your question a bit more carefully - what do you want to have happen when there are 2 details that fall under the same topic, and you delete one?

Comment: If there are two details that have the same topic then there would be two rows in the ObjectiveTopic so I would need to just remove the one row. If you don't mind can you change your answer to show the tables I use. I think that way it will make it easier for others and for me to be sure of your answer. Thanks

Comment: The problem in your case is that the constraint goes the other way, from the Topic to the Detail. On reference cascade will delete all the details if you delete a topic, but not the other way around. I will update my answer to move the constraints the way you need them

Comment: Thanks and yeah I see the problem now. So based on what you said I assume it would not be good for me to apply those two changes suggested in your edit to my ObjectiveTopic table.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ReferenceData DROP CONSTRAINT FK_MyTable

ALTER TABLE dbo.LocalData 
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ReferenceDataLocaldata_Cascade 
   FOREIGN KEY (ForeignID) REFERENCES dbo.ReferenceData(ForeignPK) 
   ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also it would be useful to **explain** what you're doing, and why you're doing it - don't just dump a pile of code on us....